# Excel: IF AND statement not working both ways

Tags: excel

I'm using a IF AND statement to check a simple statement, for example A>B&BB, I get FALSE. How is that even possible?

**My data sample:**

[image]

It works both ways if I use `AND()`, but I prefer to use `&`.

Comment: The issue is that since `&` is a concatenation you are saying `42767.36>42767.3642767.36>42787.00` which will come out as false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may *"prefer to use &"* but unfortunately this operator in Excel has a different meaning: string concatenation. If you dont want to use `AND`, you can use `*` instead; but you will need to *parenthesize* the terms.

```
 =IF((A2>C2)*(C2<B2), TRUE, FALSE)
```

Comment: Ahh, now it makes sense. I'll accept your answer as you actually explained to me what I was doing wrong. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Use `AND()`:

```
IF(AND(A2>C2,C2<B2),TRUE,FALSE)
```

Or as was written in comments you can use multiplication:

```
IF((A2>C2)*(C2<B2),TRUE,FALSE)
```

FYI - you don't need `IF()`.

If you use `AND(A2>C2,C2<B2)` the result will be Boolean (`TRUE`/`FALSE`).